# Handling double slashes in a input string using php

Tags: php

I want to store an input with double slash and single slash in database.Also i need to show the original value while displaying. 
ex: \frhnt002\sample-tr

Anybody know how to do this in php?

Thanks

Comment: Single slash: "\\" Double slash: "\\\\"

Answer (score 2):

You should escape a `\` with another backslash `\\`.

If you want to write two backslash in a string literal then you should write 4 backslash `\\\\`.

- One backslash: `\\`
- Two backslash: `\\\\`

Comment: can u send some sample to add slashes to this input.(\\test\test). I didn't get any solution.

Comment: @Sakthi `\\\\test\\test`

Comment: HI I tried str_replace function, but i am not getting corrrct output.